# Query to retrieving records by country, state,city and location in a single row

Tags: c#, sql, linq

[Table Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpapM.png) [Table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZHDZ.png)

How to get a Whole record by Query which selecting
country state,city,location in a single Row.

country Which will be select with country Id and State Parent Id will be that country Id and City Parent Id will be state Id  and Location parent Id will be city Id.

In this way how to select that related records by each location and city and state and Country.

Table Name : LocationMaster

Example:
    India, Tamilnadu,chennai,Saidapet.

Wanna Solution for this problem.

Check out this given Image Below my table structure here.

Comment: Please post code and data as text, not images.

Comment: what you didn't  understand which i have explained about?

Comment: You might want to try reading [ask] and [mcve]...

Comment: It's usually a good thing to do if you give us your table name, conditional that you wanna fillter.

Comment: You probably want to do multiple `GroupBy` operations

Comment: please Send that query bro I will try with that.

Answer (score 0):

I guest your problem is **How to convert multiple rows into columns in one row**
You can try this code:

```
DECLARE @Countries VARCHAR(500) = (SELECT ParentDescription + ',' FROM *yourtable* FOR XML PATH (''))

PRINT @Countries
```

Apply for other columns accordingly.